# ArcGIS 10's Editor and Snapping toolbars question (snapping polyline to another polyline)

Tags: polyline-creation, snapping

Have attempted this about 20 different ways using Editor / Snapping Toolbars and ET GeoWizards but still cannot find solution. Screen shot is attached. 
Need to snap the green polyline to the red polyline at specified location and back to beginning of red polyline.

[image: snapping polylines question]

Comment: Have you tried splitting the red and green polylines at the breakpoint then snapping the desired segments together?

Comment: would rather not have to split the green line since i will need to create mileposts for it once it is snapped to the red line... the Snapping toolbar is my original question, i click on "vertex snapping", select the lines, and then nothing else happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Snap tool from ArcToolbox (search for it to find it). Select only the green line, snap the feature class to itself, set your snap distance to no larger than the biggest gap between the green line and the red line. Choose edge snapping for your snapping type.

That should make the green line snap to the red line.

Comment: error 000800  screen shot: http://i.imgur.com/eQw1C.jpg

Comment: You did not set several of the snap environment arguments. Set "Type" to "EDGE" and Distance to the width of the biggest gap between the two lines.

Comment: but that will snap the entire line to the other

Comment: Only up to the snap distance though, but I could see where there would not be fine control of where the snapping started. I am thinking, since the green line cannot be split, to snap the red line at the snap point, and set the unsnapped part of the red line as low priority and the snapped part as high priority (so that the green line would only snap to the segment of the red line that it is supposed to be snapped to).

Comment: with reshape feature you pick where the snapping begins.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **Snap to Edge** (via Classic Snapping)

[image]

[image]

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001t00000047000000.htm

Answer (score 1):

you want the re-shape feature.
You cna use either the line tool while in re-shape mode or the trace tool.
[ESRI Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Reshaping_a_line_to_match_another_feature/001t000003w1000000/)
Using reshape will allow you to leave the part of the line you don't want to schange, and "re-shape" the rest.
If you use the trace tool in re-shape mode you begin by selecting the first point on the line you want to move.
The reshape must cross the begining and the end of the original line.
I do this by either editing the first an dlest vertex manually setting them on thetarget feature, or by just including them both in the re-shape and then edit afterward.
You would end by switching frmom trace to line tool and select the end vertex of the original. F2 or double click will complete the command.